# React-Redux: Loopback Cross-Origin Error when using Redux Action

Tags: reactjs, redux, cors, axios, loopbackjs

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX5HkOP-LWs&list=PLuNEz8XtB51K-x3bwCC9uNM_cxXaiCcRY&index=7) video tutorial from Rem Zolotykh. I am having the problem that querying the LoopBack server within an onSubmit() from a Form works and using a Redux Action with the same query gives me a Cross-Origin error.

- LoopBack Server running at localhost:3000
- React Webpack Server
  running at localhost:3001 (I used create-react-app)

This following onSubmit function works. Please don't mind the hardcoded stuff it is just for testing.

```
--------------SignupForm.js-----------------
...
onSubmit(e) {
    const user_data = { "email": "foo@bar.com",
                        "password": "xxx" };

    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/login', user_data)
    .then((response) => {
        auth_token = { headers: { 'Authorization': response.data.id } };
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/empsecure', auth_token)
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Queried Data:', response);
        return axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/logout',{},auth_token)
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("logged out", response);
    });
}
...
```

Here is the changed onSubmit() and the Redux Action:

```
--------------SignupForm.js-----------------
...
onSubmit(e) {
    this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state);
} 
...
-------------signupActions.js---------------

import axios from 'axios';

export function userSignupRequest(userData) {
    return dispatch => {
        const auth_token = {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'BgKeyYGVWxx5ybl649jhiPiHpZAyACmV6d9hfJ5UAJxs1McR4RaqANBgwP8vEqiH'}
        }; 

        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/empsecure', auth_token)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Queried Data:', response);
            return response
        });   
    }
}
```

The browser console gives me a Cross-Origin error, I understand that. But why does it work without redux then?

Comment: What’s the exact error message shown in the browser console?

Comment: This is what firefox says: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/empsecure. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: This is what mozilla says about this error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after researching, surfing internet and lot of code changes, 
I found its required in this case **to prevent the default action for onSubmit()**.

I think it did not like the page reload. 
Works now.

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek Kumar ;)

Comment: @VladimirF thanks for highlighting, i will never use again, thank you